# Float precision goes to the 13 when not needed

Tags: python

I am having a problem with Python's precision when subtracting.
For example if I wanted python to do `0.1234-.01` it would sometimes return `0.1134000000005`.

Why does this happen and how can I stop it?

Comment: That's how floating point numbers work. It's usually solved by formatting the number when you print it out, or using `decimal` instead of float

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html

Comment: The *precision* is always the same, `float` objects are (depending on the hardware of your system) fundamentally wrapping a primitive 64bit floating point number. As such, the usual caveats to fixed-width floating point numbers apply